# How Python does destroying the garbage?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I have a question about the behaviour of this simple function.
Here a code:

```
def foo():
    pi = 3.14
    def f():
        return pi
    return f
F = foo() 
F() # this is returning the 3.14
```

Why does the function `f` returning the 3.14? I thought, after function execution the entire local namespace should be destroing is'nt? So, the function `foo` at the end return the pointer to the declared function `f` (the function will be allocated into heap), but variable `pi` must be destroiyng as stack variable?

Comment: this is not valid python. the last line should be only `foo()`. The answer is related to scope of variables

Comment: Not to be picky, but it should probably be `foo()` as the return value from `foo` is not a function, it's the end result of `f()` and not `f` itself. I'm pretty sure this is just a type-o, you want `return f` not `return f()` (the later is returning the result of `f` and the first returns the function "pointer"). Voting to close as this is just a type-o, nothing else : )

Comment: "this is returning the 3.14" -- no, it's raising an exception because `3.14` is `float` and not callable

Comment: Your code is example of "closure". Function f() store the scope of function foo().

Comment: Sorry! I have mistake into `return` statement. I'm edited the example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does the function f return [...] 3.14? I thought, after function execution the entire local namespace should be destroing is'nt?

Yes and no.

In this case, the needed variables from the local namespace are retained as a so-called "closure" for the locally defined function. In this case, the `pi` variable remains available for this function until it is needed.

Let's elaborate a bit:

```
def foo():
    pi = 3.14
    def f():
        return pi
    return f
```

This is the outer function.

In the CLI, we can play around a bit.

```
>>> foo
<function foo at 0x000001B4E5282E18>
>>> dir(foo)
['__annotations__', '__call__', '__class__', '__closure__', '__code__', '__defaults__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__globals__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__kwdefaults__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

Ah, there is something like `__closure__`, the word I just used before. What is it?

```
>>> foo.__closure__
>>>
```

Huh?

```
>>> foo.__closure__ is None
True
```

Ah.

```
>>> f = foo() # get the inner function
>>> f
<function foo.<locals>.f at 0x000001B4E5C6C158>
>>> f()
3.14
```

Ok. Let's see what it has inside:

```
>>> f.__closure__
(<cell at 0x000001B4E5C34A08: float object at 0x000001B4E5231648>,)
```

Now what's that?

```
>>> c = f.__closure__[0]
>>> c
<cell at 0x000001B4E5C34A08: float object at 0x000001B4E5231648>
```

A cell?

```
>>> dir(c)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'cell_contents']
>>> c.cell_contents
3.14
```

Ah. So `f.__closure__[0]` is a cell, something like a container, for the value taken from the local namespace above.

As a bonus, we could look into the disassembly of the functions:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (3.14)
              2 STORE_DEREF              0 (pi)

  3           4 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (pi)
              6 BUILD_TUPLE              1
              8 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object f at 0x000001B4E5C418A0, file "<stdin>", line 3>)
             10 LOAD_CONST               3 ('foo.<locals>.f')
             12 MAKE_FUNCTION            8
             14 STORE_FAST               0 (f)

  5          16 LOAD_FAST                0 (f)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(f)
  4           0 LOAD_DEREF               0 (pi)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

Here we see how `f` is constructed:

```
      3           4 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (pi)
```

Load the variable `pi` as a closure (a cell)

```
                  6 BUILD_TUPLE              1
```

Build a tuple with only this cell

```
                  8 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object f at 0x000001B4E5C418A0, file "<stdin>", line 3>)
                 10 LOAD_CONST               3 ('foo.<locals>.f')
                 12 MAKE_FUNCTION            8
```

Make a function with the given name, code and closure

```
                 14 STORE_FAST               0 (f)
```

Store it.

In the function, the closure elements are accessed with `LOAD_DEREF`.

---

If we extend the function a bit, such as

```
def foo():
    pi = 3.14
    two = 2
    three = 3
    def f():
        return pi - three
    return f
```

we see how these variables are treated and handled:

```
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (3.14)
              2 STORE_DEREF              0 (pi)

  3           4 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (two)

  4           8 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
             10 STORE_DEREF              1 (three)

  5          12 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (pi)
             14 LOAD_CLOSURE             1 (three)
             16 BUILD_TUPLE              2
             18 LOAD_CONST               4 (<code object f at 0x000001B4E5CA36F0, file "<stdin>", line 5>)
             20 LOAD_CONST               5 ('foo.<locals>.f')
             22 MAKE_FUNCTION            8
             24 STORE_FAST               1 (f)

  7          26 LOAD_FAST                1 (f)
             28 RETURN_VALUE
```

See how the variables `pi` and `three` differ from `two`: `two` is stored with `STORE_FAST`, the others use `STORE_DEREF` so that they can be passed to the function.

```
>>> foo().__closure__
(<cell at 0x000001B4E5BC41F8: float object at 0x000001B4E5231528>, <cell at 0x000001B4E5C348B8: int object at 0x0000000050816120>)
```

This now has two elements:

```
>>> foo().__closure__[0].cell_contents
3.14
>>> foo().__closure__[1].cell_contents
3
```

And this is how it is used:

```
>>> dis.dis(f)
  6           0 LOAD_DEREF               0 (pi)
              2 LOAD_DEREF               1 (three)
              4 BINARY_SUBTRACT
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

The subtraction indeed happens inside the inner function, as the variables even could change:

```
import time
import threading

def foo():
    c = 0
    def run():
        nonlocal c
        while c < 50:
            c += 1
            time.sleep(1.0)
    t = threading.Thread(target=run)
    t.start()
    def f(): return c
    return f
```

Here, a thread increments the variable every second. If we now do `f = foo()`, we get this one inner function, which returns different values if called several times with some time between the calls.

Answer (score 0):

this code returns a number, namely `3.14`:

```
def foo():
    pi = 3.14
    def f():
        return pi
    return f()
```

Comment: Sorry! I have mistake into return statement. I'm edited the example